# how to join two bites together (the last 4 bits of each) for a whole file

Tags: python, python-3.x, byte

how to join two bites together (the last 4 bits of each) for a whole file>?
After I read the file, split it into bytes, print only the two bytes can someone please tell me how can i join two last 4-bits together of the previous 2 bytes in PYTHON?

Comment: FYI a four-bit "slice" of a byte (most commonly the upper or lower half) is called a [Nibble or Nybble](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nibble)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mask your bytes, then shift one four spaces left and use bitwise OR to join them again:

```
byte1, byte2 = twobytes[:2]  # will split out to integers
newbyte = bytes([((byte1 & 0x0F) << 4) | (byte2 & 0x0F)])
```

Demo:

```
>>> twobytes = b'\x13\x24'
>>> byte1, byte2 = twobytes[:2]
>>> bytes([((byte1 & 0x0F) << 4) | (byte2 & 0x0F)])
b'4'
```

Where 0x34 is the ASCII character for `4`, so Python displays that.

Comment: yes, i belive it will help me but how it will get the two bytes each time.? The file is 54,294 bytes.

Comment: @user3238361: you can read 2 bytes at a time with `.read(2)`; when that returns an empty value you reached EOF.

Comment: i am printing my 4-bits like this(/ is a new line)-- 0101/0100/0100/1000/0100/010 which two 4-bits is a character. How can I join the 2 4-bits every time?

Comment: @user3238361: What are those 4 bits? Python `bytes` objects? Strings? Are they literal `0` and `1` characters? How did you get those values? Perhaps a new question (with those details) is in order.

Comment: Those 4 bits is from reading a file a get the last 4 bits of each byte . Is binary code like this becasue i transfer them from hex to binary.  My problem is that I have two join every two lines the bits and then convert them to text, so i can get the hidden msg from a file.

Comment: My answer depends on the values being integers instead. You need to *show* your code for me to be able to answer your questions; otherwise there is too much guesswork involved.